# Laravel 5, update 1 row but it affects multiple rows. Why?

Tags: mysql, laravel

**Before update.**

```
mysql> select parcel_id,type, status ,accepted_at,accepted_user,submitted_at,submitted_user, updated_at from parcel_deliveries;
+---------------+------+--------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| parcel_id     | type | status | accepted_at         | accepted_user | submitted_at        | submitted_user | updated_at          |
+---------------+------+--------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| RI013502995TH |    1 |      1 | 2015-09-29 15:01:44 | hnong         | 2015-09-29 17:19:56 | hnong          | 2015-09-30 16:50:11 |
| EN064142823TH |    1 |      1 | 2015-10-02 16:17:39 | hnong         | 2015-10-02 16:48:24 | hnong          | 2015-10-02 17:12:39 |
| EN064142823TH |    2 |      1 | 2015-10-02 16:39:43 | hnong1        | 2015-10-02 16:48:24 | hnong          | 2015-10-02 17:12:39 |
+---------------+------+--------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

**Update record, I intend to update only 1 row (parcel_id = EN064142823TH, type=2)**

```
$a = App\Parcel_delivery::where('parcel_id', 'EN064142823TH')
->where('type', '=', 2)
->where('postal_code', '10170')                                                                                
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();

=> App\Parcel_delivery {#829
     parcel_id: "EN064142823TH",
     type: 2,
     status: 1,
     accepted_at: "2015-10-02 16:39:43",
     accepted_user: "hnong1",
     submitted_at: "2015-10-02 16:48:24",
     submitted_user: "hnong",
     destination_id: null,
     person_type: null,
     signature: null,
     comment: "",
     run_no: null,
   }
>>> $a->status = 5;
=> 5
>>> $a->save();                                                                                                => true
```

**After updated.**

```
mysql> select parcel_id,type, status ,accepted_at,accepted_user,submitted_at,submitted_user, updated_at from parcel_deliveries;
+---------------+------+--------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| parcel_id     | type | status | accepted_at         | accepted_user | submitted_at        | submitted_user | updated_at          |
+---------------+------+--------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| RI013502995TH |    1 |      1 | 2015-09-29 15:01:44 | hnong         | 2015-09-29 17:19:56 | hnong          | 2015-09-30 16:50:11 |
| EN064142823TH |    1 |      5 | 2015-10-02 16:17:39 | hnong         | 2015-10-02 16:48:24 | hnong          | 2015-10-02 17:14:43 |
| EN064142823TH |    2 |      5 | 2015-10-02 16:39:43 | hnong1        | 2015-10-02 16:48:24 | hnong          | 2015-10-02 17:14:43 |
+---------------+------+--------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

I didn't know why another record was update also (parcel_id = EN064142823TH, type=1).

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your table lacks a unique primary key so Eloquent cant distinguish one record from another so it can't apply the update. Add an autoincrement id primary key field to your table and I think this problem will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks. I added auto increment id as primary key and it works.

Comment: @onthemoon please tag the answer as accepted with the tick if it solved your problem.